# Why `NSObject() == NSObject()` is false but `ObjectIdentifier(NSObject()) == ObjectIdentifier(NSObject())` is true?

Tags: ios, swift

Swift code

```
print("1", NSObject() == NSObject())
print("2", ObjectIdentifier(NSObject()) == ObjectIdentifier(NSObject()))
let object3 = NSObject()
let object4 = NSObject()
print("3", object3, object4)
print("4", ObjectIdentifier(object3) == ObjectIdentifier(object4))
```

Console result

```
1 false
2 true
3 <NSObject: 0x600000d805f0> <NSObject: 0x600000d80610>
4 false
```

ObjectIdentifier compares instances using their object identifiers and the identical-to operator `===`. Why NSObject() in print("1", ...) is two object, but in print("2", ...) is same object?

Answer (score 4):

Hypothesis:

The first NSObject is *released immediately* upon obtaining the ID (evaluated as part of the left-hand-side of ==) and the second NSObject “takes its place” and is assigned the same internal address-aka-ID, such that the next ObjectIdentifier returns the same ID.

The release can’t occur in the NSObject() == NSObject() case, as the object (not the ID from evaluation) is used in the comparison operator itself. The release also can’t occur when it the object is bound to a local variable.

The hypothesis can be argued for given the following:

```
 let x1 = ObjectIdentifier(NSObject()) // NSObject #1 released
 let x2 = ObjectIdentifier(NSObject()) // Do we get same ID here?
 print("x", x1, x2)
```

Comment: I believe this hypothesis is correct because I was having a similar issue, but, once I added objects to an array, the ObjectIdentifiers became different since the array was maintaining a reference to each object, which meant that the same memory address couldn't be used for each object.